# iPhone show View half of the times

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, view, ads

I want to show a view half of the time (50%). When you click on a button it goes to a new ViewController, thats fine. But I want to show a subView on half of the time the button is clicked. This subView contains ad, so I don't want to push out the ad all the time when the button is clicked. This is my first time adding this, so I would be great if someone had a if statement for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do something half the time...

```
if (arc4random() % 2) {
  // do something
}
```